# ember, why I need to wrap append with this to work?

Tags: javascript, function, append, ember.js, handlebars.js

Im starter with ember, my question simple, I want to append a handlebar in my html, simple, but the append (in all my experiments) only work when I wrapp it with $(function(){...}). I dont want to use that (if its possible....). Any alternative, solution, suggestion?

```
<!--handlebar-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="text">
  <h1>Send the message:</h1>              
  <input {{action "clicked" on="click"}} {{bindAttr name="name_attribute"}}  value='click me!!' type="button"/>
</script>​

<script>
  //namespace
  App = Ember.Application.create();

  //define view 
  App.myview = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'text',
    name_attribute:'name_buttooooon',               
    message: '',
    clicked: function(event) {
      jQuery('#templateHere').html((this.get('name_attribute')));
    }                               
  });

  //create view
  App.myview=App.myview.create();

  //insert view in body
  $(function() {
    App.myview.append('#templateHere');  //Why I need to wrap this line in $(function(){..})???
  });

</script>

<div id="templateHere"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Does `append` require the element to be available when you call it? `document.getElementById('templateHere')` won't give you anything where you're trying to use `#templateHere`, you have to wait until that part of the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ember.Application.ready` to perform operations once the app has loaded:

```
App = Ember.Application.create(
  ready: function() {
    this.myview.append('#templateHere');
  }
);
```